# Is there a alarm clock app that uses UTC time?

Tags: alarm, clock, time-zones

Is there a alarm clock app that uses UTC instead of local timezone?

The reason I ask is that I am tired of this daylight savings time idea, so my plan is to set 1 time in a non DST timezone like UTC and then use that time as wakeup in the morning time all year.

Comment: Alernative/related: [How do I disable Daylight Saving Time (DST)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/139763)

Answer (score -1):

In Russia there is no DST anymore as of 8.02.2011. Therefore you could set your timezone to MSK and set your alarm depending on the time difference to your location.

Comment: Lucky you, no more DST :)

Comment: But you know that if you change the timezone the phone uses, then all the apps will be using the "wrong time". I would like things like calendar and logs to use the local time. It is only the alarm clock that should use UTC.

Comment: I am not in Russia, so not so lucky me :).

Answer (score -1):

That app does not exist, all the alarm clocks use the local timezone.

Comment: It's only left that all clocks run Android. Then you won't be able to do this at all :D