# Alarm with time zone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, alarm, time-zones

The stock alarm clock only allows specifying times in the local time zone.

However, I often travel across time zones, and I need a couple of alarms to happen at a given (absolute) time, regardless of the time zone where I currently am.

A related question was closed for asking about apps that would allow setting alarms in a specific time zone: [Is there a alarm clock app that uses UTC time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/is-there-a-alarm-clock-app-that-uses-utc-time)

Without asking about specific apps. Is it possible to somehow specify alarms in one specific time zone?

If that is not possible with any existing app, could anyone give any pointers that would make it possible to develop such an app?

I was thinking on somehow subscribing to changes in the time zone (maybe checking the time every 30 minutes?), and adjust some of the alarms when a change is detected. But that sounds elaborated and prone to issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why not use an already developed app from play store? eg. See if this [Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macropinch.axe) app is useful. The description says, "alarms auto adjust themselves while the time zone changes and each alarm starts with predefined settings."

Comment: @Lucky that app does not allow specifying the time zone. It only says it adjusts alarms to time zone changes; i.e. the same as the stock app does.