# How do I disable Daylight Saving Time (DST)?

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-6, date-and-time, time-zones

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6. This year, I'm doing an experiment wherein I do not participate in Daylight Saving Time (DST). However, my phone automatically adjusts itself for DST.

How do I disable this? Is there any way to stop my phone's clock from adding or removing an hour twice a year?

Answer (score 5):

Android uses [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (IANA Time Zone Database) to store time zone rules, which the Daylight Saving Time (DST) information is also included. The rules tell when DST is observed in a given time zone. Thus, it is not possible to disable the DST if using a time zone that observes DST.

Therefore, to "disable" the DST, choose a time zone that doesn't observe DST and has the same offset as the current time zone (refer to [Wikipedia's List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)).

Example:

- Brussels, Belgium (GMT+01:00) [observes DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/belgium/brussels); while it's on DST, its offset will be GMT+02:00.
- Brazzaville, Congo (GMT+01:00) [doesn't observe DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/congo/brazzaville).

*Turning off the **Automatic time zone** option* may also be needed to prevent it from being changed back to the network-provided time zone.

Comment: There's a possibility that the needed time offset doesn't have other time zones that don't/do observe DST. In this case, I'm not sure if there's a solution other than trying to create a new time zone data on `tzdata` and use it. It should be possible, but I haven't researched it.

Comment: So even when I turn off automatic time zone (and manually change from Eastern to Central) it will still change for daylight savings time?

Comment: @Supuhstar Central Time (CST/CDT) observe DST, so you can't use them. You must find another time zone that has offset GMT-06:00 and doesn't observe DST... which is [Galapagos Islands, Ecuador](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/ecuador/galapagos-islands) (if it's available...)

Comment: @Supuhstar I updated my answer to add the link to list of tz database time zones. Try it by sorting the UTC offset and find the one with same UTC DST offset.

Comment: +1. Found this while trying to answer this [bounty](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204166/131553). Thanks. Is my suggestion on comments there valid? Can you please have a look?

Comment: @beeshyams hmm, I have read that question, and I'm actually still not sure about the fix. AFAIK, unlike this question, the OP still wants to have DST applied for daily purpose, but the issue is with GPS time itself (as you have found on Strava forum). I don't know if the issue is with how the OS handling the GPS time ignoring the DST, or the apps themselves, or even the GPS sources themselves (if possible, but who know)...

Comment: You make valid points. I thought if app plus device both can be set up to DST free zone, it would solve, though my suggestion thete is only for device. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 with Android 5.0.1 and the timezone of Cairo was +3 GMT, which is wrong. When I use Automatic timezone and automatic date and time from the network, it results in two different times, one for the widget and the other for the main screen.

Finally, I found a utility which repair the timezone of my phone: [TimeZone Fixer (ROOT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.force.timezonefixer). Just try, it may help you.