# How to fix incorrect GPS time in Summer time (Daylight saving time)?

Tags: gps, time-zones, motorola-moto-c-plus

I live in the south of Brazil. At this time of year is in daylight saving time, where the time zone goes from -03 GMT to -02 GMT. The hour of my MOTO C PLUS (Android 7.0) has changed automatically to the right time without any problem, but the GPS time continues in -03 GMT Time zone.

I use an application that uses GPS time and errors are generated because of this difference. This problem is not in the application, as other users use the same version of the app without any problems and I also checked with app support.

I used GPS Status app to check that difference. I already tried do reset cached A-GPS data, but without any success.

Is there any way to change the timezone of the GPS clock?

[image: IMG:]

Uninstalling and re-installing applications does not help. This affects all applications tested below:

- [Strava](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strava&hl=EN)
- [GPS Time](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourcewalker.gpstime)
- [GPS Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) - screenshot above

Comment: @beeshyams, thank you for the tips! I deactivated automatic time zone and changed to Recife time, but that also change the hour of my phone. But when I change to South Georgia Time, which is -02GMT, the gps time got to the right time. this will serve as a temporary but not definitive solution to my problem. By the links that you passed me, this seems to be an old problem that happens with several android users ...

Answer (score 1):

## This is a workaround not a permanent solution

(OP is looking for a permanent solution as mentioned in comment but I am posting this workaround that may possibly benefit future visitors)

This problem appears to be a persistent issue as OP saw with multiple apps they tried and also reported in the Strava app forum [Incorrect Activity Time with daylight savings](https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208779298-Incorrect-Activity-Time-with-daylight-savings?page=2) and unsolved for last two years. Reasons for this are unknown but I guess it is an OS issue since multiple apps have faced this. Surprisingly, it has not been reported on Google Product Forums AFAIK.

There are two solutions mentioned in the support forum, both are temporary:

- Changing the phone time zone to non-DST zone.
- Modifying the `.gpx` file of the app to force it report correct time.

I have not attempted second solution.

**Changing the phone time zone to non-DST zone**

Daylight Savings Time (DST) seems to be related or in some way causing this. As a solution, one is required to change the time zone of phone to a time zone with the *same time* as yours but that *doesn't use Daylight Savings Time*.

**How**: Andrew T has provided an excellent answer here ([How do I disable Daylight Saving Time (DST)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/139765). It shows how a corresponding time zone can be chosen without DST while maintaining the correct time both with GPS and local time.

Based on that answer, following time zones were suggested - Cayenne /America, Recife, Montevideo (Interestingly, only some portions of OP's country Brazil follow DST , while Recife [doesn't follow DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/recife) and hence included). None of these helped but OP tried South Georgia Time which doesn't follow DST and the *GPS time was synced with local time*

This spadework may help as a temporary fix (till DST changes are revoked) or in providing a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

The GPS Status application has a setting to use UTC time.

Settings->Units & Formatting->Show UTC time

From a development point of view, it's usually simplest to using UTC time to perform all calculations, then you adjust to local time when displaying.

It's difficult for me to understand exactly how you are using this time reading, for example, whether you are automatically or manually checking.

Comment: Unfortunately changing this setting in GPS STATUS only changes the view only in the application itself, in the other applications continue with the same problem. I discovered the problem in the application strava, which uses this data to record location data during a physical activity (cycling in my case) and allows comparing the data with other users who made the same route at the same time. With the bug quoted, I can not make this comparison, because strava considers that I did the activity an hour earlier than I actually did.